# How to recover from an package uninstallation that removed everything?

Tags: package-management

I am using 13.10 in VMWare as a guest.

While trying to remove an older version of libjpeg using apt-get, somehow, the whole desktop and related applications were removed.

I have rebooted into recovery mode and it has attempted to mount my disks. However, it gets stuck during the loading of services.

It's now showing something like below and just sits there:

```
* Starting Elasticsearch Server [OK]
```

---

New development:

I have gotten into the root shell with network enabled. `sudo apt-get update` was also run.

Now, when I go and do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` it lists a bunch of dependencies, but says they will not be installed. Therefore, since dependencies were not met, install could not proceed:

[image]

If I run `sudo apt-get check`, I also get the same output.

What can be done to resolve this? I do not want to do `apt-get -f install` yet without understanding the implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve the problem.

1. Boot into recovery mode by holding down the shift key on boot. Once in the recovery mode, drop into `root shell`.
2. At this point the file system is mounted as read only. I had to modify some files to get the internet to work. So, mount the FS as read write: `mount -o rw,remount /`.
3. I then edited my `/etc/fstab` to comment out a windows share because Ubuntu wasn't able to connect to it and enabling the network fails.
4. Type `exit` to get back to the menu.
5. Enable the network from the menu.
6. Go back into root shell.
7. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`.
8. In my case, I had that error regarding dependencies being unmet, so I first did `sudo apt-get -f install`.
9. Finally do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`.
10. Reset the launcher icons to default: `unity --reset-icons`. This command crashed the system, but I got the default launch icons back on reboot.